# fastapi writing url parameters to database sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError

Tags: fastapi

I am working an an app in Fastapi (I am new to Fastapi). The app receives a GET request on the root url with url parameters, and I want to save these parameters to a database. All the examples I find are working with POST requests. I have tried several thing and get a Pydantic error (expecting a post request with body data) or a sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'app.main.User' is not mapped
.

This is the most recent code:

```
app = FastAPI()

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./camping.db"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args = {"check_same_thread": False})
session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    authtoken = Column(String(500))
    admin_id = Column(Integer)
    app_id = Column(Integer)
    lang = Column(String(20))
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    
class User(BaseModel):
    authtoken: str
    admin_id: int
    app_id: int
    lang: str
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = session() 
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/", response_model=User)
async def root(db : Session = Depends(get_db),authtoken: Union[str, None] = None, action: Union[str, None] = None,admin_id: Union[int, None] = None, chain_id: Union[int, None] = None, app_id: Union[int, None] = None, lang: Union[str, None] = None): 
    bk=User(authtoken=authtoken, action=action,admin_id=admin_id, chain_id=chain_id,app_id=app_id,lang=lang)
    db.add(bk)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(bk)
    return User(**bk.dict())
```

With this I get a pydantic error:

```
@app.get("/", response_model=User)
async def root(b1: User,db : Session = Depends(get_db),authtoken: Union[str, None] = None, action: Union[str, None] = None,admin_id: Union[int, None] = None, chain_id: Union[int, None] = None, app_id: Union[int, None] = None, lang: Union[str, None] = None): #,b1: User, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    bk=User(id=b1.id, authtoken=b1.authtoken, action=b1.action,admin_id=b1.admin_id, chain_id=b1.chain_id,app_id=b1.app_id,lang=b1.lang)
    db.add(bk)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(bk)
    return User(**db.dict())
```

The error:

```
{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body"],"msg":"Field required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1.2/v/missing"}]}
```

Comment: Are you defining two `User` classes?

Comment: There could be a problem. I will change one class name.

Comment: Yes, the similar class names were actually the problem @chc
Thank you!